# How to close/iconify SearchView after pressing on "Find" button?

Tags: android, search, searchview

I am using SearchView as described in tutorial [Creating a Search Interface](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html).
I use option android:launchMode="singleTop" to perform search in the current activity.
After pressing on "Find" button keyboard closing but SearchView remains open.
Is it possible to iconify SearchView after performing of search?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When creating the search menu item save in an instance variable

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    searchMenuItem=menu.add("Search")
        .setIcon(R.drawable.ab_search);
```

Then use `searchMenuItem.collapseActionView()` when you want to close.